# Why setting text-align to right for the anchor tag, moves the span tag which is inside anchor tag, moves out of the anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have a problem understanding why setting *text-align* property to *right* value, moves the span tag out of the anchor tag area (overflow)?

The structure of the HTML document

```css
a.btn{
  border: 1px solid #00A0D6;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #00A0D6;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;

  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

.container{
  margin: 90px;
}

.top-content{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom-content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <span class="top-content">Buy now</span>
  <span class="bottom-content">Sale for $40</span>
</a>
```

I cannot even properly center the span tag. I do not understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
You have to remove the `position: absolute` to the span, and add a `text-align: center` to the `<a>`.

If you want to keep `position: absolute`, just put `left: 100px` to the `<span>`.

**Explanation**
If you put `position:abolute`, to centered it, you have to get in mind the parent's width. If not, the `<span>`is positioning just right to it.
By other way, you have to `text-align:center`to `<a>`because you want that the content inside it, to be centered.

Comment: Yes it does work but I want to have the absolute position to the span tag.

Comment: Can I know why <span> is positioned right to it when I set position to absolute?

Comment: if you are using absolute then you are dealing with `right` ,`left` try make
`right:2px` then you will see a change

Comment: Because width `position:absolute`, _The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element_ from http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/pr_class_position.asp